# How to enter a default value when a TextBox is empty

Tags: c#, winforms, methods, textbox, operand

I have this `method` which `SUM` values in those `textboxes`, I wanted to improve it so if any of these `textboxes` is `empty` I would like to insert into it `"0"` but I didn't knew where to and what exactly put to make it work like I want. I have wondered about this for quiet long time, would someone suggest me something please ?

```
void vypocti_naklady()
    {
        double a, b,c,d,e,f,g,h;
        if (
            !double.TryParse(p_ub_s.Text, out a) ||
            !double.TryParse(p_poj_s.Text, out b) ||
            !double.TryParse(p_jin_s.Text, out c) ||
            !double.TryParse(p_dop_s.Text, out d) ||
            !double.TryParse(p_prov_s.Text, out e) ||
            !double.TryParse(p_pruv_s.Text, out f) ||
            !double.TryParse(p_rez_s.Text, out g) ||
            !double.TryParse(p_ost_s.Text, out h) 
        )
        {
            naklady.Text = "0";
            return;
        }

        naklady.Text = (a+b+c+d+e+f+g+h).ToString();
    }
```

Thanks everyone for their help and time.

Comment: @sircodesalot WinForms, thank you for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make one textbox validated event (because if empty you just need to insert 0 and not retain focus),and subscribe all other textboxes to that textbox validated event.

For example: you have 5 textboxes subscribe (by clicking for example textbox1 properties window|events and double-click validated), and for the other textboxes subscribe their validated event to that one, then inside it put this:

```
private void textBox1_Validated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (((TextBox)sender).Text == "")
    {
        ((TextBox)sender).Text = "0";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
private double GetValue(string input)
{
  double val;

  if(!double.TryParse(input,out val))
  {
    return val;
  }

  return 0;
}

var sum = this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().Sum(t => GetValue(t.Text));
```

Try the above. Just run an OfType on the parent of the text boxes (parent could be the form itself)

This will count any invalid input as 0

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
// On the textboxes you want to monitor, attach to the "LostFocus" event.
textBox.LostFocus += textBox_LostFocus;
```

This monitors for when the TextBox has lost focus (has been clicked away from). When it has, then run this code:

```
static void textBox_LostFocus(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    TextBox theTextBoxThatLostFocus = (TextBox)sender;

    // If the textbox is empty, zeroize it.
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(theTextBoxThatLostFocus.Text)) {
        theTextBoxThatLostFocus.Text = "0";
    }
}
```

If effect you watch the `TextBox.LostFocus` event. Then when the use clicks away from the box, it will run `textBox_LostFocus`. If the `TextBox` is empty, then we replace the value with a zero.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative would be not to use the `TextBox` text directly and parse it, but to databind to a property and use those instead. The `Binding` itself will do the parse and validation, leaving your variable always clean and ready for use.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    // Declare a couple of properties for receiving the numbers
    public double ub_s { get; set; }
    public double poj_s { get; set; }   // I'll cut all other fields for simplicity

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Bind each TextBox with its backing variable
        this.p_ub_s.DataBindings.Add("Text", this, "ub_s");
        this.p_poj_s.DataBindings.Add("Text", this, "poj_s");
    }

    // Here comes your code, with a little modification
    private void vypocti_naklady()
    {
       if (this.ub_s == 0 || this.poj_s == 0 /*.......*/)
       {
           naklady.Text = "0";
           return;
       }
       naklady.Text = (this.ub_s + this.poj_s).ToString();
    }
}
```

You just work with properties, already safely typed as `double` and forget about formating and parsing. You may improve this by moving all that data to a `ViewModel` class and putting the logic there. Ideally, you can apply the same idea to the output `TextBox` by databinding to it too, but for that to work you must implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` so the bindings know when to update the UI.